# iptables for ipv6 address port forwarding to localhost port

Tags: iptables, ipv6

Say I want to redirect 2a00:1450:400c:c01::71 on Port 443 to localhost Port 12345.

How to do that with Iptables?

## Update

Okey, it's Weechat which running an SSL relay on a port >=1000. It can make connections with IPv4 and IPv6 on this port. So I want to bind a defined IPv6:Port [2a00:1450:400c:c01::71]:443 to IPv6 localhost Port [::1]:12345

Comment: Don't do this. Just don't. You can't do it with iptables anyway, and there's no good reason for it. Just run your service on its proper port, or use a proper reverse proxy.

Comment: @Markus: if your question is answered don't forget to mark the correct answer as accepted

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You might cause problems because with IPv6 you're not supposed to NAT, but starting from Linux kernel 3.8 you can do:

```
ip6tables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp \
          -d 2a00:1450:400c:c01::71 --dport 443 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 12345
```

Comment: Do you know what version ip6tables is required?  I am running a 3.14 kernel, but ip6tables v1.4.14 is giving an error `unknown option "--to-ports"`.

Comment: I'm running a 3.13 kernel with ip6tables 1.4.21 (Ubuntu 14.04)

Comment: http://www.netfilter.org/projects/iptables/files/changes-iptables-1.4.17.txt

Answer (score 3):

This answer is applicable to the original version of the question, before it was edited. For the updated question, the answer given by @SanderSteffann is applicable.

You cannot do that with `iptables`, because `iptables` is handling just IPv4 and not IPv6. You cannot do it with `ip6tables` either, because `ip6tables` is handling just IPv6 and not IPv4.

There does exist protocol converters, which can convert between IPv4 and IPv6. But those may impose limitations on what IPs they can convert, because IPv4 and IPv6 don't have the same number of IP addresses.

Combining a protocol translator to change the IP address with `iptables` to change the port number may be possible. But I wouldn't advise using such a combination, in particular not without knowing details about your specific needs.

Either way, the server would not have immediate access to information about the client IPv6 address, because there is no way to embed the entire IPv6 address inside the client IPv4 address visible to the server.

Based on the limited amount of information provided, I would give the same advice that @MichaelHampton did, just run the service on the proper port in the first place. If that's not an option, then ask a better question. Explain what service you tried to run, how you attempted to get it listening on the right port, and how it failed.

Comment: I am a bit confused by your answer here.  He said he wanted to redirect to localhost, which is not inherently IPv4.  The IPv6 localhost address is `::1`.  There shouldn't need to be any IPv6 to IPv4 translation.

Comment: @Zoredache `iptables` is inherently IPv4. Additionally, those distributions I have access to at the moment has `localhost` mapped to `127.0.0.1` and a different name (like `ip6-localhost`) mapped to `::1`. It may be the OP really does have the server listening on `[::1]:12345`, in which case the question is slightly misleading.

Comment: @kasperd The default `/etc/hosts` for Debian 7 contains the line `::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback`.

Comment: @Dubu The Debian 7.5 system I checked has `127.0.0.1       localhost` on one line and `::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback` on a different line.

Comment: @kasperd The line I copied&pasted above comes from a system installed last Friday from a `debian-live-7.5.0-amd64-xfce-desktop.iso` image. I just did a new install of the same image in a VM to verify that the `hosts` entry was not caused by later packages updates, and I can definitely say: A new installation of Debian 7.5.0 from the image above creates an `/etc/hosts` file which contains `localhost` both in the `127.0.0.1` and `::1` lines, verbatim as quoted above.

Comment: @Dubu The one I looked at was upgraded from an earlier Debian version. It might be that those lines in `/etc/hosts` are generated at initial install and not updated even if the system is upgraded to a newer Debian version which would have generated them differently.

Answer (score 1):

this one worked for me, similar to @Sander Steffann but no hardcoded ip addr, just interface

```
ip6tables -t nat -I PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 2222
```